# Can I have PageReference within PageReference?

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, pdf

I am working on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/276266/generating-a-pdf-and-attaching-after-clicking-on-submit-from-vf-page) requirement. I have a SaveAction() pagereference method in my controller on the Button click from the **Input VF Page**, where I am saving the VF page's input field values to an opportunity.

After the opportunity `insert`, I am calling another pagereference method within this SaveAction() to generate a PDF (from `renderAs = "pdf"`) from a second VF page, i.e. **PDFViewer**. Here I am just referencing the fields values that are set in the actual VF page. But, every time, I get an empty valued initial VF page, but not the rendered as PDF page? Am I am missing something?

```
public PageReference SaveAction() {
   //insert Opp based on the values from the Input VF page.
    generatePDF();
    return null;
}

public PageReference generatePDF(){
    List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();
    PageReference pr = Page.PDFViewer;
    Blob pdfAsBody;
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        pdfAsBody = pr.getContentAsPDF();
    } else {
        pdfAsBody = Blob.valueOf('Dummy data');
    }

    Attachment att = new Attachment();
    att.Body = pdfAsBody;
    att.parentId = opp.Id;
    att.Name = 'attachment.pdf';
    attList.add(att);

    //Inserting the attachment. 
    if(!attList.IsEmpty()){
        insert attList;
    }
    return pr;
}
```

Comment: you might need to specify a parameters for PDFViewer page, i.e. ```pr.getParametersMap.put('Id', someRecord.Id);```

Comment: I am not passing any parameters to the PDFViewer page (URL/any that sort). Still, I tried your suggestion. I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the desired action when clicking a button/link associated with action method `SaveAction` is to return to the user a PDF page:

```
public PageReference SaveAction() {
   //insert Opp based on the values from the Input VF page.
    PageReference pdfPage = generatePDF();
    pdfPage.setRedirect(true);
    pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id',someId);  // to tell controller the object
    return pdfPage;
}
```

Comment: Hi Cropredy, looks like I still have the same issue, i.e., Attachment is still the empty Input VF page. But, as we have setRedirect = true, I am getting the PDFviewer pdf page, but with empty fields.

Comment: @AustinEvans - well, when the PDF page is rendered with setRedirect(true), it reinstantiates the controller and gets the data it needs from the controller properties of the new controller object. So, you need to make sure that the data is refetched. This probably means you have to pass a URL parameter to tell the PDF page which object to fetch.